# Deploying multiple war files into jetty8

Tags: maven, war, maven-jetty-plugin

How do I deploy multiple webapps WAR files into Jetty 8 with `maven-jetty-plugin`?

```
<contextHandlers>
  <contextHandler implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <war>${basedir}/dir/mywar.war</war>
  <contextPath>/path</contextPath>
</contextHandler>
```

Seems to work only on older plugin versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following snippet from a pom.xml. This is adapted from the Jetty server instructions, and although it's for Jetty7 it can easily be adapted for later versions.

**pom.xml**

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Jetty 7.3+ requires Maven 3+ -->
    <!-- Keep with Jetty 7.6.0 to avoid startup delays from Servlet API 3.0 -->
    <version>7.6.0.RC1</version>
    <configuration>
      <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
      <stopPort>8009</stopPort>
      <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
      <!-- Provide some JNDI resources (optional) -->
      <jettyEnvXml>src/test/resources/jetty-jndi-config.xml</jettyEnvXml>
      <!-- Register this application as a context -->
      <webAppConfig>
        <contextPath>/example</contextPath>
      </webAppConfig>
      <!-- Allow resources on the test classpath to be available -->
      <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
      <!-- Add in any supporting application contexts (use dependencies section) -->
      <contextHandlers>
        <!-- Supporting WAR (note the use of a property entry for version, and see the dependency later - also Jetty 7 uses org.eclipse...) -->
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <war>
            ${settings.localRepository}/org/example/supporting-war/${supporting-war.version}/supporting-war-${supporting-war.version}.war
          </war>
          <contextPath>/supporting-war</contextPath>
        </contextHandler>
      </contextHandlers>
      <connectors>
        <!-- Later versions of Jetty don't require the Connector to be specified -->
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <port>8080</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
        <!-- SSL for localhost support -->
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
          <port>8443</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
          <!-- Provide a local key store for serving up SSL certificates -->
          <keystore>src/test/resources/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
          <!-- Pick any password you like -->
          <password>jetty6</password>
          <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
        </connector>
      </connectors>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- This ensures that WAR files are downloaded from the repo -->
      <!-- Example supporting WAR  -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>supporting-war</artifactId>
        <version>${supporting-war.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>war</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

I've left the SSL and JNDI configuration in there just in case anyone needs to see how they are configured. Obviously, they will need the supporting files. The SSL assumes that you've already created a suitable key store containing an SSL certificate for, say, localhost. The JNDI configuration file is as follows:

**jetty-jndi-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="ExampleDB" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>java:jdbc/ExampleDB</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <Set name="driverClass">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</Set>
        <Set name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/schema</Set>
        <Set name="user">user</Set>
        <Set name="password">password</Set>
        <!-- Configure a simple connection test with timeout for subsequent queries -->
        <Set name="preferredTestQuery">select 1 from dual</Set>
        <Set name="checkoutTimeout">5000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

This will allow a JNDI resource lookup using, for example, a Spring bean factory like this:

```
<bean id="exampleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jdbc/ExampleDB"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
  </bean>
```

Note that the C3P0 and Oracle references will introduce dependencies that are ostensibly local to your Jetty server, so should be placed in the `<plugin><dependencies>` section along with the WARs. They don't have to be in the main dependencies.

So now your Maven build will contain an embedded Jetty web server, configured to work with multiple WARs, all tied into the pom.xml version, providing both HTTP and HTTPS and backed with a pooled database connection. That's pretty much everything you need right out of the box for an integrated development environment.